# Is it possible that an ASP.NET httpContextBase ever be null? or Request? or UserAgent?

Tags: asp.net, null, httpcontext, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm getting a bug in a production server. I know which line is, but I do not know which would be the one that is complaining of a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Something is null:

```
public string GetAgentType(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
{
  try
  {
    string userAgent = httpContextBase.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();
    /*some code to return the agent type*/
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    /*..Log exception logic..*/  
  }
}
```

The method is called with the injected parameter ControllerContext.HttpContext from a controller class.

```
"string userAgent = httpContextBase.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();"
```

As I said not pretty sure which would be null; httpContextBase? Request? or UserAgent? or in which cases one of them could be null?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` can be `null` if called from a thread not associated with a HTTP request. The `httpContextBase` _parameter_ in your code **could** be `null` because you haven't shown us **exactly** how it's being called/used (e.g. attempting to construct a new `ControllerContext` from within a non request-thread using `HttpContext.Current`) , which can also happen after an `await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Also, _annoyingly_, [`ControllerContext.HttpContext` is a mutable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.httpcontext?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) (which is idiotic, imo), so there _could_ be code elsewhere in your application which simply sets the property to `null`